# Corda throws error trying to generate the basic nodes

Tags: corda

Am trying to generate the basic nodes- PartyA, PartyB and Notary on Ubuntu 14 by running ./gradlew deployNodes or even ./gradlew clean deployNodes. The error reads:

... still waiting. If this is taking longer than usual, check the node logs.

Error while generating node info file /cordapp-template-java/build/nodes/Notary/logs

Error while generating node info file /cordapp-template-java/build/nodes/PartyB/logs

Error while generating node info file /cordapp-template-java/build/nodes/PartyA/logs

> Task :deployNodes FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.

  > Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in /cordapp-template-java/build/nodes/Notary/logs.
  >   Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in /cordapp-template-java/build/nodes/Notary/logs.

The error logs do not provide any indication of error.

Comment: ./gradlew clean build then you can use ./gradlew deployNodes

Comment: Use "./gradlew --stop" before running "./gradlew deployNodes"

Comment: I upgraded to Ubuntu 18. Now running well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally run into the above question myself. From what I saw, it seems it was a random incident on the Unix based machine.

The issue was resolved after I moved the project to the different location. It is absurd. But I have never ran into this issue ever again.